# $\mathcal{F}$ is a class of holomorphic functions on the open unit disk, when are they normal

Tags: complex-analysis

The following problem is taken from Rudin's real and complex analysis, exercise 15 of chapter 14.

Problem: let $\mathcal{F}$ be the class of holomorphic functions on the open unit disk $U$, such that $\text{Re }f>0$ and $f(0)=1$. Show that $\mathcal{F}$ is a normal family. Can the condition $f(0)=1$ be omitted? Can it be replaced by $|f(0)|\leq 1$?

Can you please help me check my solution to make sure I'm not making any blunders? Thanks!

My attempt: define $g=\frac{f-1}{f+1},$ then $g:U\rightarrow U$ is holomorphic and $g(0)=0$. By Schwartz lemma, we see that $|g(z)|\leq |z|$. If $\alpha\in(0,1)$ is fixed, then if $|z|\leq\alpha$, we have $$\bigg|\frac{f(z)-1}{f(z)+1}\bigg|\leq\alpha.$$ Since $$\bigg|\frac{f(z)-1}{f(z)+1}\bigg|\geq\frac{|f(z)|-1}{|f(z)|+1},$$ this implies that $$|f(z)|\leq\frac{1+\alpha}{1-\alpha}$$ if $|z|\leq\alpha.$ This shows that $\mathcal{F}$ is locally bounded, hence normal. The condition $f(0)=1$ cannot be omitted. A counterexample: $f_n(z)=n$ for $n=1,2,...$. If we merely assume $|f(0)|\leq 1$, then $|g(0)|<1$, let $h:U\rightarrow U$ be given by $h(z)=\frac{g(0)-g(z)}{1-\overline{g(0)}g(z)}$, apply Schwartz lemma to $h$, it is clear that $f$ is again uniformly bounded on $D(0,\alpha)$ if $\alpha\in(0,1)$. Hence we are allowed to assume $|f(0)|\leq 1$.

Comment: In your definition of $g$, how do you justify that $f \neq 1$?

Comment: Also, locally bounded families are not normal, locally _uniformly_ bounded families are normal.

Comment: most everything is good but the difference between the two families is that one is closed, the other not since $h(z)=0$ is a limit point when you assume only $|f(z)| \le 1, f \in \mathcal{F}$; this may or may not matter since technically normal is usually taken as the closure has to be compact